# recurrence relation n rabbits

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A single pair of rabbits (male and female) is born at the beginning of a year.  Assume that 1) rabbit pairs are not fertile during their first month of life but every month after that they give birth to two new male/female pairs at the end of each month and 2) no rabbits die.  Find a recurrence relation for the number of male-female rabbit pairs at the end of month n.  How many rabbits will there be at the end of 12 months?

I know this is a recurrence problem and I know how to solve one when I understand the situation for this one. I just want to understand this particular problem and how we can related to recurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$ with $f_1 = 1$ and $f_2 = 2$. Then $f_n$ will be the number of pairs of rabbits after $n$ months. The sequence is the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). It is $f_{12} = 233$, so there are $233$ pairs of rabbits after $1$ year.